# How to sum 2 or more fields and Insert the result in another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I have 2 tables.

table1:

```
workers_attendance
ID  Name   Day01  Day02  Day03  Day04  Day05  Day06  Day07
1   xxxx   1      0      2      3      4      1      4
2   zzzzz  2      1      3      1      0      4      3
3   yyyy   0      0      0      1      3      3      4
```

It has number because the workers have different sites to work. 
(Ex. 0=absent, 1=hospital, 2= Park  3=Police station 4=Beach)

and there is the table 2:

```
workers_total
ID    Name    Totaldays
```

Only 3 fields..

How can I count all the days in `workers_attendance` and add them to `workers_total`?
like this

```
ID   Name   Totaldays
1    xxxx   6
2    zzzz   6
3    yyyy   4
```

Is this possible: `SUM(count(day01)+count(day02)...)`

Comment: I think you should start from another approach, your table it's not the best way to do it, check it out [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an insert statement from the following select

```
select ID, Name, 
  IIF([Day01] > 0, 1, 0) + IIF([Day02] > 0, 1, 0) + IIF([Day03] > 0, 1, 0) +
  IIF([Day04] > 0, 1, 0) + IIF([Day05] > 0, 1, 0) + IIF([Day06] > 0, 1, 0) +
  IIF([Day07] > 0, 1, 0) AS TotalDays
from workersw_attendance;
```